# Main class in Game Of Life isn't working

Tags: java, program-entry-point, conways-game-of-life

I was trying to solve the Game of life problem for a teacher. Rules of that game are:

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies, as if caused by under-population. Any live cell with two or three live neighbors’ lives on to the next generation. Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies, as if by overcrowding. Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

There are two problems with my code - first of all, my main class doesn't seem to be working. Secondly, I performed the problem through many many if else statements. Are there more concise ways of writing the exceptions for my getNeighbors() method?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GameOfLife {
final static int ROWS = 6;
final static int COLUMNS = 7;
String[][] simulator;
private Random randomGenerator;

public GameOfLife() {
    simulator = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    randomGenerator = new Random();
}

public void fillSpot (int row, int column) {
    simulator [row][column] = "O";
} 
private void deleteSpot (int row, int column) {
    simulator[row][column] = "";
}
// Do I need the above methods? really?
public void randomSimulation() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= COLUMNS; j++) {
            int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(1);
            if (random == 1) {
                fillSpot(i,j);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void getNeighbors (int row, int column) {
    int neighbors = 0;
    if (row < ROWS && row > 0 && column < COLUMNS && column > 0) {
        for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = column - 1; j <= column + 1; j++) {
                String temp = simulator[i][j];
                if (temp.contains("O")) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (row > ROWS || column > COLUMNS || row < 0 || column < 0) {
    }

    else if (row == ROWS && column < COLUMNS && column != 0) {
        for (int i = row - 1; i <= ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = column - 1; j <= column + 1; j++) {
                String temp = simulator[i][j];
                if (temp.contains("O")) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (row < ROWS && column == COLUMNS && row != 0) {
        for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = column - 1; j <= COLUMNS; j++) {
                String temp = simulator[i][j];
                if (temp.contains("O")) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (row == 0 && column < COLUMNS && column != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = column - 1; j <= COLUMNS + 1; j++) {
                String temp = simulator[i][j];
                if (temp.contains("O")) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (row == 0 && column == COLUMNS) {
        for (int i = row; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = column - 1; j <=COLUMNS; j++) {
                String temp = simulator[i][j];
                if (temp.contains("O")) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (column == 0 && row < ROWS && row != 0) {
        for (int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = column; j <= COLUMNS + 1; j++) {
                String temp = simulator[i][j];
                if (temp.contains("O")) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else { 
        for (int i = row; i <= row + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = column; j <= column + 1; j++) {
                String temp = simulator[i][j];
                if (temp.contains("O")) {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // for row == 0 && column == 0
    if (simulator [row][column].contains("O")) {
        neighbors--;
    }
    simulator[row][column] += " " + neighbors;
}
//There are wayyy too manyy clauses here for me to be comfortable. There's got to be    a way to do this cleaner

private void nextGenPlanning() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= COLUMNS; j++) {
            getNeighbors(i,j);
        }
    }
}

private void nextGen() {
    nextGenPlanning();
    for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= COLUMNS; j++) {
            String temp = simulator[i][j];
            if (temp.charAt(temp.length()) <= 1 ||  temp.charAt(temp.length()) >= 4) {
                deleteSpot(i,j);
            }
            else {
                fillSpot (i,j);
            }
        }
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String string = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        string = string + "|";
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
            String temp = simulator[i][j];
            string = string + temp.charAt(0);
        }
        string = string + "|\n";
    }
    return string;
}

public String simulate (int numOfTrials) {
    String string = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfTrials; i++) {
        nextGen();
        string += toString();
    }
    return string;
}

public void main (String [] args) {
    randomSimulation();
    System.out.println(simulate(2));
}   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". What output are you expecting? What output are you getting? What did you see when debugging and stepping through the code (if you haven't done this, do this first)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have:

```
public void main (String [] args) {
    randomSimulation();
    System.out.println(simulate(2));
}
```

You should have:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    GameOfLife game = new GameOfLife();
    game.randomSimulation();
    System.out.println(game.simulate(2));
}
```

Second, for getNeighbors, first consider that a 'get' method usually returns a value. If you're counting the number of neighbors, consider:

```
public int getNeighbors(int x, int y) {
  int neighbors = 0;
  int leftX = Math.max(x-1, 0); 
  int rightX = Math.min(x+1, COLUMNS); 
  int topY = Math.max(y-1, 0); 
  int bottomY = Math.min(y+1, ROWS); 

  for (int i=leftX; i < rightX; i++) {
    for (int j=topY; j < bottomY; j++) {
      if (simulator[i][j].contains('O')) { // Notice I'm using a char here, see my next comment
        neighbors++;
      }
     }
   }

   return neighbors;
}
```

Third, I recommend using `char[][]` instead of `String[][]` for your simulator if each space in the simulator only holds one character value. There are some things about Strings in Java that you don't need to get tripped up with - for example, in Java, you cannot compare the value of Strings using == (you need to use String's `equals()` method).

Answer (score -1):

First , your main class should be `Public static void main(String[] args)` and you can use switch case except of if else if you really sure on if else you can use if ( blabla == blablabla &(this means and ) blaba == babalaba)

Comment: Not a main "class", but a main method, and the signature should be `public static void main(String[] args)`